# Django-tastypie: Any example on file upload in POST?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

Could anyone give a complete example on using the tastypie FileField, both server-side and client-side please?

Here's what I have tried:

```
#models.py
class Foo(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="images", null=True, blank=True)
    body = models.CharField()

#api.py
class FooResource(ModelResource):
    img = fields.FileField(attribute="image", null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Foo.objects.all()
```

If I try to create a foo object using curl, e.g.,

```
>>> curl -F "body=test" -F "img=@local_img.png" http://localhost:8000/api/0.1/foo/
```

A foo object is successfully created, but the `img` field is null. I can see in debugger that when saving the bundle object indeed has a img field which contains a `InMemoryUploadedFile` object, so the request is probably ok.
Where am I doing wrong? Code snippets are most welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your Resources should look like this:

```
class FooResource(ModelResource):
    img = fields.FileField(attribute="img", null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Foo.objects.all()
```

The `attribute` should correspond to the field in the model.
As stated in the documentation:

> ApiField.**attribute**
>
> A string naming an instance attribute of the object wrapped by the Resource.

Comment: When I do this, I get the error: `The format indicated 'multipart/form-data' had no available deserialization method.` Am I missing something simple?

Comment: I found a solution to the missing deserialization error [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522332/how-to-access-post-data-inside-tastypie-custom-authentication), based on [this github post](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/42#issuecomment-5485666).