# How do you upload a file with a POST request on django-tastypie?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django-tastypie: Any example on file upload in POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381016/django-tastypie-any-example-on-file-upload-in-post)

I currently do cURL POST requests to my API like so

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"username":"theusername", "api_key":"anapikey", "video_title":"a title", "video_description":"the description"}' http://localhost:8000/api/v1/video/
```

but now I need to be able to add a video file to the upload. I have been looking around for a few hours about uploading files with Tastypie and I have not come up with one solid response. Do I need to add the Base64 encode? If so how? How do I acces the file after I have uploaded it with a POST request? Just normal request.FILES actions? I am not looking to save the file to the database, just get the path to the file.

```
#Models.py
class Video(models.Model):
    video_uploader = models.ForeignKey(User)
    video_path = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    video_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    video_description = models.CharField(max_length=860)
    video_title = models.SlugField()
```

I am thoroughly confused on how to implement a file upload system for Tastypie so any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Here is way to upload file by `MultiPart` through `django-tastypie`.

**Models.py**

```
class Video(models.Model):
    video_uploader = models.ForeignKey(User)
    video = models.FileField(_('Video'), upload_to='path_to_folder/') # save file to server
    video_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    video_description = models.CharField(max_length=860)
    video_title = models.SlugField()
```

**Api.py**

```
class MultipartResource(object):
    def deserialize(self, request, data, format=None):
        if not format:
            format = request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json')
        if format == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
            return request.POST
        if format.startswith('multipart'):
            data = request.POST.copy()
            data.update(request.FILES)
            return data
        return super(MultipartResource, self).deserialize(request, data, format)

class VideoResource(MultipartResource, ModelResource):
   """
   Inherit this Resource class to `MultipartResource` Class
   """
   # Assuming you know what to write here 
   ...
```

And then through `CURL`

```
curl -H "Authorization: ApiKey username:api_key" -F "video=/path_to_video/video.mp3" -F "video_title=video title" http://localhost:8000/api/v1/video/ -v
```