# Django-Tasypie image upload example with JQuery

Tags: jquery, django, file-upload, tastypie

I'm looking for a way to implement client side file (image) upload from jquery to Django-Tastypie.

So far server side seems correct testing with CURL:

I found this post helpfull [Django-tastypie: Any example on file upload in POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381016/django-tastypie-any-example-on-file-upload-in-post)

EDIT : This is what i did with curl ->

```
in api.py :
    class MultipartResource(object):
        def deserialize(self, request, data, format=None):
            if not format:
                format = request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json')
            if format == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
                return request.POST
            if format.startswith('multipart'):
                data = request.POST.copy()
                data.update(request.FILES)
                return data
            return super(MultipartResource, self).deserialize(request, data, format)


    class FooResource(MultipartResource, ModelResource):
        img = fields.FileField(attribute="img", null=True, blank=True)
        class Meta:
            queryset = Foo.objects.all()
            authorization= Authorization()


in models.py :
class Foo(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="images", null=True, blank=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Then running the following command with curl :

```
curl -v  -F "body=test" -F "img=@my_picture.png" http://localhost:8000/api/v1/foo/
```

Now i'm trying to do the same with jquery as client instead of curl.....with no luck.
It's difficult to find a working example for Jquery+Tastypie for file upload...

If you have any simple example available thanks for sharing

Comment: show us your curl that worked and you were happy with and we can show you how to do that in jquery

Comment: Just added the sample which works with curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean using `$.ajax()` or `$.post()` then it won't work because Ajax doesn't support file uploads. See e.g. [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery).

There are some workarounds though - e.g. uploading via form in hidden iframe or flash-based solutions - they are discussed in the SO post mentioned above. None of them are perfect though, so you will have to choose the one which best serves your use case.

Comment: Thanks i'll test the method !

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody stumbles upon this in the future, I got image upload working (which was working using `curl` already) in my case using [this jquery File Upload Demo on github](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html).

Use the Basic file upload:

1. Include necessary js files (jquery, jquery-fileupload,
   iframe-transport, and jquery.ui.widget).
2. Initialize the target `input[type=file]` control as shown below

**Code:**

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
```

This should do the trick.