# Image name with path in tastypie

Tags: android, django

I have used this code to make my `api` in `django tastypie it` works perfectly i want to get the image name with path which is saved in my media file how will i get it i tried img.path and `img.name` but it didn't work the link is

> [Django-Tasypie image upload example with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263964/django-tasypie-image-upload-example-with-jquery?lq=1)

and secondly i make this request through my android application and i want to send a string to my application in response containing information how will i send it???

Comment: How is your model defined? Is it an ImageField? A FileField? Some other third-party image-based model?

Comment: Yes it is an image field as stated in above link